# Does Angular have a predefined object that houses all current promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a controller where I can allow everything except one function ( let's call it thatOneFunction() ) to run asynchronously. The reason for that is thatOneFunction() relies on roughly 10 promises to have been resolved otherwise it does not have the data in the scope it needs to execute.

I have seen multiple examples online of how you can specifically grab the promise of individual gets/queries/services but what I have not seen is a way to check that all promises at once have been solved - perhaps by virtue of an Angular state variable that I am just not aware of? Something like:

```
var currentPromises = $state.promises;
currentPromises.then(thatOneFunction());
```

Or if not already a built-in variable is there a way to dynamically generate a list of all promises outstanding at the current moment that I can then use .then()?  It would assist a lot because I will have many pages in this application that have this structure.

**What I have tried/am currently doing**"
As of right now I have a work around but it requires some hardcoding that I'd rather not continue. It is based on inserting a call to a function that checks a counter of how many times that function has been called, compares it to how many promises should have called that function already (hardcoded after counting the the promises in the controller) and if it has already gone through all the required promises it then calls thatOneFunction().

Thanks for any help/pointers.

***Example bits of my code (real names/variables changed):***

**Controller**

```
$scope.runAfterAllPromises = function() {
               *code dependedent on all promises here*
}

MySvc.loadList(function (results) {
        $scope.myList = results;
    });


$scope.runAfterAllPromises();
```

**Service**

```
app.service("MySvc", ['$resource', function ($resource) {


    this.loadList = function (callBackFunction) {
        var stateRes = $resource('/api/ListApi');
        stateRes.query(function (ListResults) {
            if (callBackFunction && typeof (callBackFunction) === 'function') {
                callBackFunction(ListResults)
            };
        })
```

Comment: I seriously doubt such an object exists. promises aren't tied to any particular state or scope, and can be passed around between them.

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker)

Comment: @ODelibalta Looking into it now - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain promises, if that helps?

so something like this:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(yourPromise1());
promises.push(yourPromise2());
promises.push(yourPromise3());
$q.all(promises).then(function(){ ...});
```

This what you mean?

Comment: Yeah this is the closest thing I have come across on other sites so it is very close to what I know I am able to do I was just wondering if angular was tracking it in $state in a some how accessible way. If so it would then able to not have to do all the individual pushes to the promises array but just call some built in array that was tracking currently outstanding promises. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Do you know how I could implement this when I am calling a service with a callback function and not the api directly? I am having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: Does your service return the promise? Guess it might be easier if you show some code in your Q :)

Comment: No it does not - in my controller when I call the service I pass a call back function that essentially sets $scope.controllerVariable to the results of the API query. When the API query executes it then pushes its results to the call back function. When I push the results back should I include the promise and then push that promise like you did in your answer? And If I do that in my main controller since the promises array won't initially have the promise until it is actually fulfilled will .then run since it may get to it without having any promises in the array yet?

Comment: I added a rough example sans my work around at the moment. (Imagine it with multiple services doing the same thing)

Comment: It sounds, and I may be wrong in my understanding, that you're going to find yourself in a sticky situation before you know it. Sounds like you're mixing up concerns. Ideally your service should do its job and then return a result. Your controller then acts on the result, rather than your controller passing in what the service should do once it's finished (this is the mix of concerns; your service method should do one thing, not multiple). If you change this so that it returns the promise, you'll have a much easier time as you can do things like those in my answer.

Comment: Just saw your example. Definitely going to be a pain to maintain in the future. An example of one of my service calls looks like : `this.getSettings = function (showMask) {
        return httpSvc.get(END_POINT + 'index', showMask);
    }` - where httpSvc.get is returning the promise. Each method has a single purpose and is not concerned with doing anything else

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the services should only return promises - I should then use .then() in my controller on those individual promises to save the results of the service to my scope (as well as pushing them to array to check they are all resolved like your main answer)? And sorry I am in the middle of learning Angular still and am inheriting the main structure from others on my team some of which are no longer on my team.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. no need to be sorry either, we all have to learn :) Just always bear one thing in mind when you're developing - If your method is doing more than 1 job, it's too big. That applies here too. So your service can return a promise and your controller will do what it needs with that promise. Your service shouldn't care less about WHAT is being sent back in that promise either. it should be pretty dumb

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, no such object exists.

Now, how to achieve what you want to achieve:

```
var allPromise = $q.all([promise1, promise2, promiseN]);
allPromise.then(success).catch(error);
```

Edit: After your "A man can dream comment" I thought to add this:

You could override the $q.defer function, and track all deferred objects created, and get their promises.

Obviously this could have some issues with deferreds created, but never resolved and such, but may be the simplest way to achieve your desired functionality. If you want to go the whole way, you can look at angular decorators which provide a framework of functionality for extending angular providers